# Connect esc controller to LiPo battery

Tags: connector, motor-controller, lipo

How do I connect the following battery and esc controller? They don't seem to fit as it is. Do I need another connector?

11.1V 2200mAh 3S 30C Smart LiPo Battery IC3
[image: LiPo battery]

GoolRC 3660 3300KV Brushless Motor 60A ESC 6V/3A BEC for 1/10 RC Car USA P3F9
[image: esc controller]

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Andoer-T-Plug-Female-Connector-Adapter/dp/B00Q49673U) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @vali. Why does the following seem to have same description but looks so different. https://www.ebay.com/itm/312706187043

Comment: I really have no idea, but at least you know what to look for now.

Comment: Sure thank you. It appears to be out of stock on amazon, so looked for it on eBay and got confused